# How to use CloudFront to serve static assets while site is using CloudFlare to do SSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, amazon-web-services, heroku, cloudflare

I have a rails application that I am hosting on heroku and I am using CloudFlare so that I can use HTTPS for my website.  When I try to serve my static assets through AWS CloudFront, the assets don't come through.  I can't seem to figure out why.  I don't have an SSL Certificate that I can upload to AWS CloudFront.  I am just using SSL for my website through CloudFlare.  Not sure how I can use CloudFlare and CloudFront together.

Comment: If you link to your assets using the CloudFront-provided hostname, e.g. `https://jozxyqkexample.cloudfront.net/`,  instead of using your own hostname, you get to use the CloudFront SSL certificate for free.  Have you tried that?

Comment: What do you mean?  I have a CNAME on cloudflare that points the AWS Cloudfront-provided hostname to my https domain.  I put the AWS Cloudfront-provided hostname within the production.rb file.